# Folder weekly backup?

Tags: windows, backup

I want to backup a folder on my hard drive every in another folder under say a new folder saying backup-01-01-2010?

Also if it is possible to schedule this on a weekly basis?

Comment: Is there a reason windows backup won't work for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Syncback Freeware](http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/) allows you to do that. You can schedule the backups whenever you like and using special variables, you can specify the date as part of the destination backup folder. See an example [here](http://2brightsparks.com/bb/viewtopic.php?p=26670).